# Rich GUI UX for ASP Webpages - c# webapplication

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

First things first..
My apologies if this is a duplicate post.. Correct me, redirect me if needed..

We are developing a C# ASP.Net Web application, an ERP-Software that needs attention on User Experience.
I'm very new to programming as well as designing, that I'm looking for ways to make my Web Application with rich GUI UX, something like the one shown here.. [carecloud.com](http://carecloud.com) 
When searching, I came across twitter bootstrap but i'm not sure how far that can be implemented here.
FYI: We are going to deploy our application that would be run at client side only on Internet Explorer.

Here is a screenshot of what sort of UX we want. http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/7269/carecloud.png

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is an excellent start, there are also several extensions to that framework which provide additional features such as http://bootswatch.com/ for themeing etc. Be aware that bootstrap has issue with Internet Explorer 6 - as long as your required browser version is above this though you should be fine. Consider also looking into jQuery and jQuery UI too as they also get you a long way toward creating a great UX/UI.

With regard to using C# Web Application , I assume you're using Web Forms as apose to MVC - if you are then implementing the correct HTML layout is much more easily acheived by using server side html tags rather than web controls e.g.

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="Link1">Some Link</a>
```

rather than

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Link2" runat="server" Text="Some Link 2"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Reason being is that you can control the rendered HTML more more with the server side HTML tags rather than the built in controls which may be necessary in order to match your HTML layout with the layout required by the bootstrap css.

If you wanted to make life easier for yourself rather than including jQuery/jQuery UI directly you  could use the Juice UI http://juiceui.com/ framework which is a Web Forms wrapper around jQuery UI available through NuGet here http://nuget.org/packages/JuiceUI  - you will still need to include bootstrap although this is in Nuget too here http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap .

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help. But I'm sorry I'm not aware of whether my application is MVC or Webforms. I guess it is more of MVC. I wasn't aware of such one existing.

Comment: Ahhh if its MVC your using youll have jQuery out of the box (and jQueryUI I think) so just grab bootstrap and you're set.

Comment: I'm sorry, You mean I cannot implement jQuery effects on my asp webpages, if its a MVC application?

Comment: Yes you can, I just meant to say  that when you create a new MVC project jQuery and jQuery UI should be already in place - they come by default with MVC projects. So all you would need to do on top of that is to add Bootstrap from Nuget and you're good to go!

Comment: That's a very good approach to a starter like me. Thanks for tolerating my silly questions.